# Path to CPLEX in Python

Tags: python, system, cplex

I want to use CPLEX with Python. I've added path

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64
```

to the system but

```
import cplex
```

it's not working.

It only works if I add the path in the program explicitly, that is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/python/3.7/x64_win64')
import cplex
```

Do you have any idea why adding the path directly to the system variables is not working?

Comment: did you try adding it to the PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: Thanks! I added it to PATH instead of PYTHONPATH and that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Good to hear! Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CPLEX path to `PYTHONPATH`.

Windows:
`My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`
and modify it

Linux:
`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your/CPLEX/path"`